# Visual Basic Compiler keeps crashing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

The question really says it all. For one project I am working on, the Visual Basic Compiler crashes resulting in me having to restart my IDE.

It looks like it crashes when copying a PDB file and XML file for the web site for obj/debug to the output folder.

Has anyone experienced similar crashes? If so how did you repair it?

Are there any crash logs stored anywhere??

I am using visual Studio version 
8.0.50727.762 (SP .050727-7600)

Comment: It would help if you said which version you're using.

Comment: How do you conclude that the crash is related to the copying of the pdb and xml file?

Comment: I only assume this due the fact that this is the action that is carrying out when it consistantly crashes

Comment: Only time I've seen VS crash while compiling was when I had a self-referencing property. I believe that was fixed in SP1.

Comment: Are you using the default output locations, or is it set to output directly to a local IIS site or test server?

Comment: Oh, and have you tried completely uninstalling visual studio and .Net, and then re-installing?

Comment: Are there any error messages at all that might help or does it just disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contincually hitting send error report to microsoft I finally got a little message box saying "We think this might be your problem" with this [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942124)

I believe this is my problem... I have still to obtain the hot fix

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually get an error message or code when it crashes, or do you just get the "Visual Studio stopped working" error message?

I'd second trying to uninstall, reinstall, and reapply SP1, just to make sure it isn't something with your installation. I've never had the VB compiler crash on me, and I'd imagine that permissions problems and other exceptions moving a file would be completely covered within the compiler's internals.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the event viewer in Administrative Tools to see if any logs were recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't running [Visual Studio 2005 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=BB4A75AB-E2D4-4C96-B39D-37BAF6B5B1DC&displaylang=en). We had tons of VBC crashes before SP1 -- it was a wonder they even made to RTM on the product.  Just terrible.  Install Service Pack 1 and your problems will most likely go away.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried cleaning your solution/project?

Sometimes the .suo, .ncb and other files maintained by Visual Studio get corrupted resulting in crashes during complilation or debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete .SUO file and get Nirvana :)